# How to save ZIP in-memory-file-object in Python

Tags: python, zip

With zip file object initiated as `fileobj`:

```
import io, zipfile, time 

filepath = '/temp/my_file.bin'

fileobj = io.BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(fileobj, 'w') as zf:
    data = zipfile.ZipInfo(filepath)
    data.date_time = time.localtime(time.time())[:6]
    data.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as fd:
        zf.writestr(data, fd.read())
fileobj.seek(0)
```

I want to save the file to a local disk. How to save the `fileobj` as a local zip file `my_zip.zip`?

Comment: use filename in `ZipFile("my_zip.zip", "w")` and then you don't need BytesIO

Comment: if you need to use `BytesIO` - `open("my_zip.zip", "wb").write(fileobj.read())`

Comment: Got it! Fixing...

Comment: @furas With `ZipFile("my_zip.zip", "w")` approach the zip file will be saved locally on a machine. With the `fileobj = io.BytesIO()` the zip file is kept in a memory.

Comment: if you want to save it locally then why to keep in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file) will help you here:

```
import time, zipfile

filepath = '/temp/my_file.bin'
local_path_to_write = 'my_zip.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(local_path_to_write, 'w', compresslevel=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.ZipInfo = zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file(filepath)
    # if you really need to edit the time attribute:
    # zf.ZipInfo.date_time = localtime()[:6]
    zf.write(filepath)
```